# horner algorithm- fast Exponentiation

Tags: java

I have to create an methon which can fast make a^x. There is a task to use a horner scheme. I was looking on a lot of webside to find some  informations about honer(because i did't have it at school) and so on. And my question is: Is it possible to do it without class Math?

Comment: Horner scheme is good for polynomial evaluation. You probably want something like this instead: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible, upon pure logical grounds: how does the `Math` class implement itself without the `Math` class already available? You can check `Math` source code, it's 100% Java, no native calls.

Comment: But if I want to do it like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring , basic method, I still need Math.pow

Comment: Sure you don't. You can implement it yourself. It's based on the  *squaring* primitive, and here is the implementation of that: `return x*x;`.

Comment: You can implement `pow` method yourself. There may be several ways to do it. Refer the following page to get an idea about this. http://www.careercup.com/question?id=14959760

Comment: now it's ok?

static double potegowanie(double x , double n){
        double wynik =0;
        if(n == 0) wynik = 1;
        if(n%2 ==0) wynik= Math.pow(x*x,n/2);
        if(n%2 !=0) wynik = x*Math.pow(x*x, (n-1)/2);
        return wynik;

Comment: It looks like you are missing the whole point of that Wikipedia section. You have literally implemented the basic relation, which is just the generative idea, and a proof of correctness, of the actual algorithm which follows below it, and which uses nothing but squaring.

Comment: now is good,

static double potegowanie(double x , double n){
        double wynik =0;
        if(n == 0) wynik = 1;
        else if(n%2 ==0) wynik= potegowanie(x*x,n/2);
        else if(n%2 !=0) wynik = x*potegowanie(x*x, (n-1)/2);
        return wynik;